# Adding Discount entity to ERD of Online Shop?

Tags: database, erd

I want to add Discount entity to my ERD of online shop, but as we can see in my ERD there is a loop between discount, cart and cart item. As you know we have 2 kinds of discount, one that is calculated on each cart item and one that calculated on whole basket total price. Could you please help how can i change this ERD that avoids loop?

[image: You can see my ERD here.]

Comment: It seems to me that in your model, a *discount* is really just an attribute of a **Cart Item** and a **Shopping Cart**. It makes no sense to model it as a separate entity.

Comment: Thanks! but  my scenario was a little complicated to have just one attribute of discount.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean with discount?

- is it just an amount to be deducted ?
- is it a discount code with a percentage for calculation, e.g. `("Promotion xyz", -5%, "vegetables")`?

The solution will depend on this and on what you want to express with your loop:

- Is it just the amount to be taken off on some items and some additional overall discount amount on the cart? Then consider, as Janez suggested in the comments, to have two different discount attributes, one in each entity.
- Or is it even the amount to be taken off on some items, and the aggregated total calculated for the cart?  Then have an item discount attribute only,  and calculate the toal on the fly for the cart.
- Is it a discount code and the same discount code is reminded at cart level?  Then simply remove the link from cart to discount: it can be found back from the items whenever needed.
- Is it different discounts, one calculated on individual items (e.g. "damaged item"), and the other applying to whole carts (e;g. "special member discount"),  then you may consider two distinct discount entities,  since the data has a different semantic and different rules and is used in a different way in each case.
- Now in the last case,  you could keep the visual loop: in reality it's a `0..1` cardinality on the discount side:  so one discount could apply only to one item whereas another discount could apply only to the total; the loop is only optical and not necessarily in the data.

Comment: Thanks for your complete answer, i forgot to mention the scenario, and the third scenario was my issue. The best way is to have 2 discount entities, one related to cart, and one which is normalized and is product-discount entity. for each product we have different and special kind of discount.

Comment: @SarahGhanei I see. But fir the cart, is it just a summary of the other discounts, or is it an independent discount calculated on the total of the cart?